# Parse query to sort list by location

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have this:

***Table*: Shop**

***Row*: business (Pointer to Business object)**

**-------**

***Table*: Business**

***Row*: location (geoPoint)**

I have more columns for each table, but these are the ones that relate to the question.

I want to obtain all the `Shops` and sort them by how nearast location (the nearest shop appears at the beginning of the list and the farthest appears at the end).

I tried this:

```
ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery(Table.SHOPS.table);
query.include(Table.SHOPS.BUSINESS);

query.whereNear(Table.SHOPS.BUSINESS + "." + Table.SHOPS.LOCATION, HGeoPos.curPosition);
```

but it fails.

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this ?

**EDIT**

Please note, I need to do this in one query 'cause I'm using the `ParseQueryAdapter`

Answer (score 0):

Is HGeoPos an appropriate class? I think you may need to convert your coordinate to a ParseGeoPoint.

Comment: No, it's fine, it's just a custom class in which i store a static object. It's the current location of the device, so i don't retrieve it every time.

Comment: But it needs to be a ParseGeoPoint object and not Android's native class. At least that's how it works in iOS, the CLLocationCoordinate2D is not compatible directly with ParseGeoPoint.

Comment: I'm using the Parse SDK to retrieve the current position, and that one returns a ParseGeoPoint. So it's fine ...